# Numpy Array to C++ - take ownership of data

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Is it possible to pass data from numpy to C++ and take ownership of the numpy.data's memory, so its no longer managed by Python? I have large Numpy matrix and I dont want to copy memory. I can use py::buffer_info and get pointer to the data, but the pointer is not valid when Python is shut down. Another reason is I want to release data from C++ side once I no longer need them.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?